# Predicted Responses as Weighted Averages: Classical Regression Vs. Mixed Effect Models

Tags: regression, random-effects-model, prediction

Let's imagine that I have collected data in a longitudinal design that would lend itself to a mixed effects analysis.  So suppose I perform a research study with human subjects and observe responses ($Y_{ij}$), where $i$ designates the subject and $j$ designates the trial, where the $j$th trial involves a possibly repeatable combination of covariates.

In mixed effects models, the "predicted value" for the true response of the $i$th subject on the $j$th trial ($\widehat{Y_{ij}}$) is a weighted average of the response that was actually observed, $Y_{ij}$, and the population averaged mean-response profile, $X_i \widehat{\beta}$.  How much each term is weighted depends, roughly speaking, upon the relatively "size" of the between-subject vs. within-subject variability.

Is there an analogue for OLS linear regression?  That is, is it similarly possible to express the "predicted value" for the response, $\widehat{Y_i}$ as a weighted average of the observed response, $Y_i$ and something else?

Comment: *"In mixed effects models, the "predicted value" for the true response of the ith subject on the jth trial (Yijˆ) is a weighted average of the response that was actually observed, Yij, and the population averaged mean-response profile, Xiβˆ."* This is not quite right as stated. Do you perhaps mean to say that the predicted subject-level **coefficients** (not the predicted values at the observation level) are a weighted average of the coefficients computed using only that subject's data and the coefficients computed from a simple regression of all of the data?

Comment: I think whether you agree with this rephrasing is important because it guides how we will answer your question (at least, it will for me). The question then becomes about whether we can express the OLS regresion model coefficients ($\beta$) as involving a weighted average of observations, or something... In any case, please clarify.